# Adapters and DialogView - Not sure how to build the Adapter

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-adapterview

So Im trying to populate a Dialog with a list of Folders that I get from an API, once the user clicks on a folder, I again populate the Dialog with its subfolders etc. But Im not quite sure how everything fits together. So far the Dialog is displayed, now I need to add the actual content.

```
 @Override
 protected View onCreateDialogView() {

    LayoutInflater inflater = ((SettingsActivity) ctx).getLayoutInflater();
    View vw = inflater.inflate(R.layout.channel_content_view, null);
    ListView lv = (ListView) vw.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    File[] files = ChannelHandler.getChannels();
    HiddenChannelsListAdapter adapter = new HiddenChannelsListAdapter(ctx, files);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    return vw;
 }
```

Im not sure how that Class *HiddenChannelsListAdapter* must look.

This is what I have sofar:

```
package com.example.tvrplayer;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

public class HiddenChannelsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public HiddenChannelsListAdapter(Context ctx, File[] files) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        View view = null;
        Log.i("ADAPTER", "Hello");
        return view;
    }

}
```

When I try and open the dialog now, it gets a NullPointerException, that I asume is because the adapter is not doing anything but returning null.

What does an adapter return? Where does it return it? Im quite confused at the moment

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
public class ContactListCursorAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

/** Remember our context so we can use it when constructing views. */
private Context mContext;

/**
* Hold onto a copy of the entire Contact List.
*/
private List<ContactEntry> mItems = new ArrayList<ContactEntry>();

public ContactListCursorAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ContactEntry> items) {
     mContext = context;
     mItems = items;
}

public int getCount() {
     return mItems .size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
     return mItems .get(position);
}

 /** Use the array index as a unique id. */
public long getItemId(int position) {
     return position;
}

/**
* @param convertView
*            The old view to overwrite, if one is passed
* @returns a ContactEntryView that holds wraps around an ContactEntry
*/
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ContactEntryView btv;
    if (convertView == null) {
         btv = new ContactEntryView(mContext, mShow.get(position));
    } else {
         btv = (ContactEntryView) convertView;
         String name = mShow.get(position).getName();
         btv.setNameText(name);
         String number = mShow.get(position).getNumber();
         if (number != null) {
              btv.setNumberText("Mobile: " + mShow.get(position).getNumber());
         }
    }
        return btv;
}
}
```

Comment: In my case I will not return a File[] list, but rather a JSONArray.